# Reflexive closure Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have this problem I can't figure out.

Suppose R is a relation on A, and let S be the reflexive closure of R. Prove
that if R is symmetric, also is S.

Could you suggest me how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(x,y)\in S$. You need to show that $(y,x) \in S$.

- Case $x=y$. Trivial.
- Case $x \neq y$. Then we observe $(x,y) \in R$ and finish the proof based on the symmetry of $R$.

Comment: Sure, my problem is to show that $(y,x) \in S$

Comment: In the second case:  you get a) $(x,y)\in R$ so you get b) $(y,x) \in R$ so you get c) it is in $S$. You need to justify each step. But  which step is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the reflexive closure, we are only adding points (from the diagonal) that cannot be a counterexample to symmetry..